# How to fix code highlighted in red in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, highlight

This happened suddenly after I restarted my computer, all of a sudden any code I type is highlighted in red. Does anyone know how to fix this? See image.

OS: Windows

[image]

UPDATE:
This is the weirdest thing, I simply restarted my computer (again), and it just disappeared. It's a shame, because I didn't get to figure out how it happened, but it's good to know about this Bisect feature in VS Code!

[image]

Comment: what if you disable all extensions

Answer (score 7):

This might have something to do with one of your extensions acting up.

VScode has a nice feature to help you find the specific extension that's causing problems without you having to check each one individually.

[VScode bisect function](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect).

Press `crtl+p` then type `bisect`

Comment: Great feature to know about! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be one of your extensions that makes this. You can check it by disabling them one by one(ctrl + shift +X and then choose installed). I guess maybe an extension that belongs these:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubs1N.png).
Hope helpful.

Comment: It's a pity if I didn't help you. Do you find what extension it is? If the Blackgaurd's answer solved your problem, you can mark it to help people find the solution!